# Shrinking directory sizes on an ecryptfs filesystem

Tags: ecryptfs

The root directory of my ecryptfs filesystem has grown massively since I accidentally created many thousands of files in it.  Now that I've deleted the files, I'd like to shrink the directory, as I believe it's causing some performance problems.

My home directory before the ecryptfs mount:

```
dr-x------ 2 ian ian 4096 May  4  2012 /home/ian
```

and after:

```
drwx------ 104 ian ian 42721280 Jun 18 13:46 /home/ian
```

https://serverfault.com/questions/264124/shrink-reset-directory-size discusses a similar problem with an ext3 filesystem, and suggests doing an `e2fsck -D`.  However, ecryptfs doesn't seem to have its own fsck.

How can I shrink my directory without creating a new filesystem and copying everything over?

Comment: Have you checked that it's not in fact the underlying filesystem that has this directory size?

Comment: Yep -- have added details to the question.

Comment: You're comparing different directories. `/home/ian/` (in ecryptfs) correlates to `/home/ian/.ecryptfs/...` (somewhere in the underlying filesystem).

Comment: Gah, you're right, I'd completely misunderstood how it works.  I'd imagined ecryptfs as a big monolithic blob that gets mounted as a filesystem, whereas in fact there's a one-to-one mapping between encrypted and plaintext files.  If you want to correct my stupidity in an answer, I'd be happy to accept it :)